# Matlab RGB color representation ([255 255 255] and [1 1 1])

Tags: image, matlab, colors

What's the difference between above two representation of white color? I'm a bit confused, and how they are used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two equivalent representations are

```
uint8([255 255 255])
```

and

```
double([1 1 1])
```

These are just the integer and floating-point representations. Note that `uint8([1 1 1])` will be (almost) black and that `double([255 255 255])` will usually cause an error.

Note that the integer version is only generally permitted by the image-handling functions, like `imread`, `imwrite` and `image`. Everything else will expect the floating-point representation.

Answer (score 4):

These two representations of white color refer to the RGB color model in which Red, Green and Blue lights are added together (additive color model) to produce the desired color.

Each one of the three basic light is usually coded with an 8 bits integer which therefore ranges from 0 to 255 (0 meaning total absence of this light).

In Matlab, these codes are often normalized by 255 and are floats between 0 and 1. Note that this is not the case when you open an image using `imread` for exemple, so you have to be careful and refer to the relevant parts of the documentation.

Example: if you want to specify a particular color with an RGB code for a plot you can use `plot(data,'color',[0 1 1]);`. This plot your data with the color cyan (green+blue).

See [Matlab color specification](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html) for other ways of specifying colors in Matlab.